# Merging two libraries

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, parse-platform, android-kenburnsview

I am using `Parse` as a *back-end service* for my app and also `KenBurnsView` library to animate the images.

My problem is that Parse uses *ParseImageView* and KenBurnsView uses `com.flaviofaria.kenburnsview.KenBurnsView`, so is there a way to merge this two together and make them function. The same questions apply to other libraries as well. Like merging two libraries about `ListViews` that have different functions so merge them together and use functions from both.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the only way to achieve this today is by making one of the `ImageView` implementations extend the second. I don't know if `ParseImageView` is open source, but I believe that making `KenBurnsView` extend `ParseImageView` will solve your problem. You have to test it yourself.